# Parsing HTML from XML description tag with illegal characters

Tags: html, xml, parsing, character, qml

I'm using a QML XmlListModel to display XML feeds which works. Except the formatting is off due to HTML being contained in the description tag below.

```
<description>&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="http://news.yahoo.com/north-korea-issues-military-threats-founders-birthday-000221193.html"&gt;&lt;img src="http://l1.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/aSYzNa8DFZPW0FCALm20Yw--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTg2O3E9ODU7dz0xMzA-/http://media.zenfs.com/en_us/News/Reuters/2013-04-15T141115Z_1_CBRE93E0OEY00_RTROPTP_2_KOREA-NORTH.JPG"
    width="130" height="86" alt="North Korean soldiers, workers and students place flowers before statues of Kim Il-sung and Kim Jong-il at Mansudae in Pyongyang" align="left" title="North Korean soldiers, workers and students place flowers before statues
    of Kim Il-sung and Kim Jong-il at Mansudae in Pyongyang" border="0" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;By Ju-min Park and Jack Kim SEOUL (Reuters) - North Korea made new threats of military action on Monday as the reclusive nation celebrated the anniversary of its founder&amp;#039;s
    birth, stoking tension on the peninsula with a new &amp;quot;ultimatum&amp;quot; to South Korea in the stand-off over its nuclear program. The latest statement from Pyongyang followed threats of nuclear attacks on the United States, South Korea and Japan,
    after new U.N. sanctions were imposed in response to the North&amp;#039;s latest nuclear test in February. ...&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br clear="all"/&gt;
</description>
```

I assume since characters like `<` and `>` aren't allowed in XML the HTML becomes since the characters were replaced.

I'm using the model below which works except some issues happen when the description contains HTML text that's been altered.

```
XmlListModel {
    id: model
    property string feedUrl: rss.activeFeed
    source: "http://" + feedUrl
    query: "/rss/channel/item"
    property ListModel temp
    property int action
    XmlRole { name: "title"; query: "title/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "link"; query: "link/string()"}
    XmlRole { name: "description"; query: "description/string()" }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your HTML and long URL's with CDATA Tags, XML will except the illegal characters that way:

```
<description><![CDATA[

&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="http://news.yahoo.com/north-korea-issues-military-threats-founders-birthday-000221193.html"&gt;&lt;img src="http://l1.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/aSYzNa8DFZPW0FCALm20Yw--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTg2O3E9ODU7dz0xMzA-/http://media.zenfs.com/en_us/News/Reuters/2013-04-15T141115Z_1_CBRE93E0OEY00_RTROPTP_2_KOREA-NORTH.JPG"
    width="130" height="86" alt="North Korean soldiers, workers and students place flowers before statues of Kim Il-sung and Kim Jong-il at Mansudae in Pyongyang" align="left" title="North Korean soldiers, workers and students place flowers before statues
    of Kim Il-sung and Kim Jong-il at Mansudae in Pyongyang" border="0" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;By Ju-min Park and Jack Kim SEOUL (Reuters) - North Korea made new threats of military action on Monday as the reclusive nation celebrated the anniversary of its founder&amp;#039;s
    birth, stoking tension on the peninsula with a new &amp;quot;ultimatum&amp;quot; to South Korea in the stand-off over its nuclear program. The latest statement from Pyongyang followed threats of nuclear attacks on the United States, South Korea and Japan,
    after new U.N. sanctions were imposed in response to the North&amp;#039;s latest nuclear test in February. ...&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br clear="all"/&gt;

]]></description>
```

Comment: Well then you should be able to tell whatever script is pulling the HTML to wrap it in CDATA Tags. Check tyhis out and see if you cant inject this in your code somewhere... http://api.jquery.com/wrap/ Hopefully that will help you otherwise I will need to know more about what method you are using